# Почему в python не компилируются в .exe аудио и картинки .jpg?

Tags: python, аудио, jpeg, gif

Написал программу на Python, она идеально работает в консоли и в разрешении .pyw, но после того, как я скомпилировал её в .exe файл, в программе не сработала музыка, не отображались картинки, для которых прописана GIF анимация, хотя библиотеки все есть.

Помогите решить проблему. Почему компилятор не компилирует .jpg, .wav, .mp3 и .gif?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Компилятор не компилирует программу, которая имеет аудио и картинки если в кратко

Comment: Потому что компилируеться только код. Так и должно быть. Просто поместите нужные медиа-файлы рядом со своей программой. Но если вам уж очень хочеться скомпилировать программу вместе с медиа-файлами - то можете посмотреть в Интернете как это сделать. Но я не рекомендую так делать.

Comment: Спасибо большое,  за ответ )